# Relative Clause - Ask for more understandings

Tags: grammar

For example, this is the sentence which is picked out from the Oxford English Grammar Course Book.

> The man that looks after our garden has had the accident.

I want to inquire that can we leave out the phrase *The man that looks* in the sentence above.

Please let me know because I see the answer for it on the book and it showed that we can remove that phrase but I'm confused whether it is true or not.

Comment: It is not true that you can omit the words _the man that looks_. Can you tell us exactly what the answer says or looks like. For example, are first four words in brackets or crossed out?

Comment: 'that looks after our garden' can be omitted to leave a valid matrix sentence with the same basic meaning (but less specification about 'the man').

Comment: @Shoe As you said and I have checked on the book. Then, the first four words are crossed out in the answer. Well, I think the writer or publisher perhaps made it wrong here.

Comment: Yes, the book is wrong. As Edwin Ashworth says, the defining or restrictive relative clause (_that looks after our garden_) is the only part of the sentence that can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your shares and explanations. They're very useful for my knowledge.

Comment: I'd rather use The man Who, not that. As identified by whether we can remove the phrase, "The man who looks after our garden" is different from "The man, who looks after our garden," as to how critical the phrase is. If critical, I am leaving out the commas. If secondary, commas.